# Retry restTemplate pos on response body parameter

Tags: kotlin, spring-retry, spring-resttemplate

I'm making integration with a web service. There is an api post method that can return a "good" response with a body like:

```
{
    "result": "Ok"
}
```

or if something bad happens it returns this:

```
{
    "result": "Failure"
}
```

I need to retry the POS request until i get a good answer.
Could anyone advice some technique to deal with this?

There are few more retry cases that depend on other response field values, but i think that the `result` property example shows the problem.

It seems, that using `RetryTemplate` would fit, but i'm not sure how to handle ths case with `RetryState`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep trying forever, use an `AlwaysRetryPolicy` in the `RetryTemplate`; check the result and throw an exception for failures.